# Inner join only if a field is not empty

Tags: mysql, join

I could have done what I want with two request, but I want to make it with only one.

In fact, I have 4 tables with :

```
Table 1 : id, sub-id
Table 2 : id, sub-id
Table 3 : id, login
Table 4 : id, login
```

I make a request like that :

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.sub-id, Table2.id, Table2.sub-id, 
   Table3.login, Table4.login FROM Table1
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table1.sub-id = Table2.sub-id)
   INNER JOIN Table3 ON (Table3.id = Table1.id)
   INNER JOIN Table4 ON (Table4.id = Table1.id)
   WHERE Table1.id = "my_id" AND Table1.sub-id = "my_subid"
```

I want to join `Table3` only if `id` is not empty, if it is empty, I join `Table4`.

Do you have any ideas please ?

I've heard that a left join could help, but I'm not that accustomed to these keywords so ...?

Comment: If you can guarantee that the id's in Table 3 and Table 4 will not be equal then the above query would be fine. Otherwise you would need to look dow the dynamic SQL route I think.

Comment: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000976.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like said in the other answers, you can use a left join. You can also add [case statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) to have only one `login` column :

```
SELECT 
    Table1.id, 
    Table1.sub-id, 
    Table2.id, 
    Table2.sub-id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Table3.id IS NOT NULL THEN Table3.login
        ELSE Table4.login
    END CASE AS login
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table1.sub-id = Table2.sub-id)
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON (Table3.id = Table1.id)
LEFT JOIN Table4 ON (Table4.id = Table1.id)
WHERE Table1.id = "my_id" AND Table1.sub-id = "my_subid"
```

Comment: `COALESCE(Table3.login, Table4.login)` gives exactly the same result with your `CASE ... END CASE`.

Comment: @ypercube in this precise case, we can assume that yes, but since the condition is on the `id` column and we want the `login` column, it's not exactly equivalent, there's some case where the results won't be the same.

Answer (score 9):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.sub-id, Table2.id, Table2.sub-id, 
Table3.login, Table4.login FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table1.sub-id = Table2.sub-id)
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON (Table3.id = Table1.id)
LEFT JOIN Table4 ON (Table4.id = Table1.id)
WHERE Table1.id = "my_id" AND Table1.sub-id = "my_subid"
```

Then, rows from Table3 and Table4 will be joined if there is a match. Otherwise, these will be `NULL`. You can then check the results and use data from either Table3 if present, or Table4 otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.sub-id, Table2.id, Table2.sub-id, 
    COALESCE(Table3.login, Table4.login) AS login
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table1.sub-id = Table2.sub-id
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.id = Table1.id
LEFT JOIN Table4 ON Table4.id = Table1.id
WHERE Table1.id = 'my_id' AND Table1.sub-id = 'my_subid'
```

I've removed unnecesary parethensis to reduce clutter. Also, please note that the standard string delimiter in SQL is the single quote.

Comment: @ypercube - Not usual on me :)

Answer (score 3):

If, for any `table1.id`, **either only** `table3.id` **or only** `table4.id` will match, you can use this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.id
  , Table1.sub-id
  , Table2.id
  , Table2.sub-id
  , COALESCE(Table3.login, Table4.login)
    AS login

FROM Table1
  INNER JOIN
     Table2 ON (Table1.id = Table2.id
            AND Table1.sub-id = Table2.sub-id)
  LEFT JOIN
     Table3 ON (Table3.id = Table1.id)
  LEFT JOIN
     Table4 ON (Table4.id = Table1.id)

WHERE Table1.id = "my_id"
  AND Table1.sub-id = "my_subid"
```

Comment: @LostInJoin: You can accept Alvaro's answer. It's the same as mine and he posted first.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.sub-id, Table2.id, Table2.sub-id, 
   Table3.login, Table4.login FROM Table1
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table1.sub-id = Table2.sub-id)
   LEFT JOIN Table3 ON (Table3.id = Table1.id)
   LEFT JOIN Table4 ON (Table4.id = Table1.id)
   WHERE Table1.id = "my_id" AND Table1.sub-id = "my_subid"
```